# Honda Civic SI 2008 Starting issues

Tags: honda, starting, civic

So I started having this issue quite a while back where when I try to start my car, the lights in the instruments panel go dead and start flickering real fast and holding the key to the start position does start the engine after about 5 seconds but shuts off due to it not recognizing the key fobs security chip, the Car does start after a few tries.
So after seeing this my first assumption was the battery, But this battery was 2 years old, so I didn't change that part I changed the Alternator instead.

After Changing the Alternator, The problem persisted with the same exact issue. So I told myself that the issue had to be the starter motor. I did realize that when the motor was being started that it was getting slower each time and I haven't changed that part ever in my vehicle, so it was time to change it anyways but now I am out of options.

What could be the issue?

I have not changed the relay but I assumed it was good because I can hear a really fast ticking sound when trying to start the vehicle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are definitely dealing with low voltage symptoms.

Personally I would suspect the battery first. The age of it means little. I would also check the connections for the battery and clean them. Make sure to check both ends of the ground wire.

Another problem I see a lot that causes these exact symptoms is when the interior fusebox/bcm (whatever honda wants to call it) gets water damaged. Not sure about the 08 civics but I know many others where the water gets in under the windshield somewhere along the firewall and leaks almost directly to the module.

Comment: hmm will look into that then, just started my car 3 times without any issues and I don't like intermittent issues because they're the worst lol

Comment: It did it to me again but this time no power, So I checked the ground wire and there it was all frayed at the connection part of it (it was hidden by a plastic cover), I was able to twist the ground wire clockwise so the connection would be solid enough to start the car and drive to get a new ground wire. Thanks for the help !