# Troubleshooting Slow Start on 2009 Civic Si

Tags: honda, starting, civic, power

The Civic takes a couple of seconds (2-3s, 5s at absolute worst) to start most of the time, but usually not after very short drives as of 2 months ago. It *is* progressively getting worse, but slowly. 160k on the car, manual transmission. My best description of what happens is that it doesn't seem to be getting juice - my first thought was the battery. Here is what was done so far:

1. Now: Got battery tested at AutoZone, supposedly good. 2 to 2.5 year old Duralast Platinum. Swapped spark plugs to new Laser Iridium. I also cleaned the terminals, etc, but they were fine - zero corrossion.
2. 2 year ago - replaced starter and a bunch of relays. The issue WAS definitely the starter. ([Thanks for the help Paulster](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/85457/manual-2009-civic-si-doesnt-start-initially-intermittent)). It "feels" different than that time, where the starter spun for a while. Here it feels like power cuts. New battery terminals.

Given this information, what is my logical next step or thing to swap? Just to give context, I am fairly experienced, but I still find it faster to just swap parts. I am hoping for some heuristics from others before I just swap the fuel pump, injectors, fuel pressure regulator, coils, etc at random hoping it's one of those before I come back to the starter which takes ages on this car. At the very least, what would be YOUR first go to swap / troubleshoot here?

I read a [related thread](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/80820/honda-civic-si-2008-starting-issues) and it's suggesting that this is a power issue, which I suspect (even though AutoZone claims "ok cranking amps"). Should I just swap the battery first? If not, could it be the ignition coils?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the cables to the starter and ground. Look to see if there are any bulges in them. It could be that there is corrosion in the cables which would act like a big resistor inside the cables and not allow as much juice to flow through, which would cause the starter to be sluggish.

While you're checking the cables, you'd want to check all connections at both ends of the cables to ensure there's no corrosion there and that they are tight. This may entail taking the connections off, inspecting, and reconnecting.

From your description, this would have nothing to do with a fuel pump, injectors, fuel pressure regulator, coils, etc. None of these cause the engine to spin slower during startup. Unless you have a bottomless pocket book or feel like these parts need to be changed, it would basically be a waste of money.

Comment: Thanks as usual Paulster. I will check the wiring. The starter takes a good four hours for me to get to, so that's not fun, but I guess it is what it is. Would be ironically painful if I went through all this last time only to either miss a corroded wire or fail to tighten a contact point. Though the wiring to the starter is fairly flimsy iirc, so could see something going wrong there.

Comment: @VSO - Realize you may not see corrosion directly. Corrosion inside the wire will appear as bulges in the external sheathing. Some of it you can do visually, but other parts you may need to just feel it. Cleaning the connections may do it for you.

Comment: Paulster - the mystery deepens, I found that it only happens when the fan is on. I guess the bad wire is somewhere related to the fan then. Still, this answer is very helpful and I don't think I would have noticed if "bad wire in whatever is on" wasn't on my mind. Thanks again and will update as usual whenever I fix it.